function for sorting contours of a Sudoku, top to botton and left to right?
i am trying to get a sorting of the contours found in this image:
Box Result:

Temporaly the contours are found like this:
img_bw=cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

(thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(img_bw, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(im_bw.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

boundingBoxes = [cv2.boundingRect(c) for c in ctrs]
(cnts, boundingBoxes) = zip(*sorted(zip(ctrs, boundingBoxes),key=lambda b:b[1][0], reverse=False))


But I would like to sort from top to bottom and left to right.
The Problem is, that some contours are smaller like marked in the picture:
This are the x,y coordinates:

so i would like to take only the 81 areas which are red and a square. And sort it from top to bottom and then left to right. So take out the first 9 boxes in the first row and sort it with the y coordinates.
Thx a lot.
BR kami
Is shown in the Question.

My method will work for any sudoku image without any process to draw the contours. In my example I will use a sudoku from sudoku.com website but it works perfectly fine with your image too.
In my approach I will use a more reliable way to detect, extract and sort the 81 squares of the sudoku in any sudoku picture.
The image of the sudoku I will use:


read the image in gray scale:

import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# reading the image directly in grayscale
image = cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)


Detecting the edges and transforming the image from gray tones to a binary black and white one

# Edge detection with Canny function
img_bin = cv2.Canny(image,50,110)
dil_kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
# dilatation of the edges
img_bin=cv2.dilate(img_bin,dil_kernel,iterations=1)

Result of img_bin:


Selecting only horizontal edges

line_min_width = 40 # minimum width of the selected lines

kernel_hprizontal = np.ones((1,line_min_width), np.uint8) # mask
img_bin_h = cv2.morphologyEx(img_bin, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel_hprizontal)

Result of img_bin_h:


Selecting only vertical edges

kernel_vertical = np.ones((line_min_width,1), np.uint8)
img_bin_v = cv2.morphologyEx(img_bin, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel_vertical)

Result of img_bin_v:


Merging the vertical and horizontal lines

img_bin_final=img_bin_h|img_bin_v
final_kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
# Dilatting the edges for easier shape detection
img_bin_final=cv2.dilate(img_bin_final,final_kernel,iterations=1)

Result of img_bin_final:


Splitting in different regions the sudoku grid

ret, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(~img_bin_final, connectivity=8, ltype=cv2.CV_32S)

# THIS CODE IS ONLY USED TO SHOW THE REGIONS IN DIFERENT COLORS ########
# Map component labels to hue val
label_hue = np.uint8(179*labels/np.max(labels))
blank_ch = 255*np.ones_like(label_hue)
labeled_img = cv2.merge([label_hue, blank_ch, blank_ch])

# cvt to BGR for display
labeled_img = cv2.cvtColor(labeled_img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

# set bg label to black
labeled_img[label_hue==0] = 0
########################################################################

Result of labeled_img:


Selecting only the 81 sudoku squares

percentage_limit = 0.15 # percentatge of error for the area of the sudoku squares

# Selecting the shapes with more than 1000 of area and with a square shape (height and width (h and w) must be similar by and error of 10)
boxes = [[x,y,w,h, w*h] for x,y,w,h,_ in stats if w*h>1000 and abs(w - h) < 10]
# median of the areas of the selected squares
median = np.median(np.array(boxes)[:,4])
# using the median to choose the 81 squares corresponding to each cell of the sudoku with an error of 'percentage_limit'
boxes = [x for x in boxes if x[4] > median*(1-percentage_limit) and x[4] < median*(1+percentage_limit)]
if len(boxes) != 81: # Simple error check
    print('Error: The number of cells is not 81')


Finally sorting all squares. The result will be a matrix with the correspondant square of each sudoku position

boxes = sorted(boxes, key=lambda x: x[0])
result = []
for row in range(9):
    result.append(sorted(boxes[row*9:(row+1)*9], key=lambda x: x[1]))

For example box[0] will return the first row of the sudoku and box[0][1] will return the square in the first row and second column.
Hope it helps!

Hi, thank you also very much. I tested both and just have really good results. BR kami

@kami If it helps accept the answer as correct. Thanks!

With the amount of red in the cell borders, you can find the boxes by extracting  highly red pixels. This can be found by taking the red channel minus the mean of the blue and green channels, then clipping to zero.  Then discretize the remaining red channel to create a bw map.
imgage_bgr = cv2.imread('path/to/image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img_very_red = (
    image_bgr[:,:,2].astype(np.int32) - image_bgr[:,:,:2].sum(axis=-1)//2
).clip(0).astype(np.uint8)
_, img_bw = cv2.threshold(img_very_red, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)


Then you can find the contours as a list, get the bounding boxes, and calculate the areas and aspect ratios.
ctrs, _ = cv2.findContours(img_bw, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
bounding_boxes = [cv2.boundingRect(c) for c in ctrs]
areas = [w*h for _,_,w,h in bounding_boxes]
aspects = [h/w for _,_,w,h in bounding_boxes]

We expect the the areas to have 81 of approximately the same value and the aspect ratios to be close to 1.  First we find the bounds of the areas by looking at a histogram of the log of the areas (otherwise the large areas blow out the binning).
counts, log_edges = np.histogram(np.log(areas), bins=10)
area_ix = (counts==81).argmax()
area_min, area_max = np.exp(log_edges)[ix:ix+2]

cell_bboxes = [
    bbox for bbox, area, aspect in zip(bounding_boxes, areas, aspects)
    if (area_min < area < area_max) and (0.95 < aspect < 1.05)
]

Sorting the cells L to R and T to B is not as easy as just a sorted call.  The x,y locations might be off my 1 or 2 pixels from cell to cell.  I would use a clustering algorithm such as k-means or mean-shift clustering to group the x positions and y positions.
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

mean_width = np.mean([c[3] for c in cell_bboxes]).round()
initial_cluster_centers = np.arange(9).reshape(-1,1) * mean_width
x_kmeans = KMeans(9, init=initial_cluster_centers )
y_kmeans = KMeans(9, init=initial_cluster_centers )
x_labels = x_kmeans.fit_predict(np.array([[b[0]] for b in cell_bboxes]))
y_labels = y_kmeans.fit_predict(np.array([[b[1]] for b in cell_bboxes]))

# L to R then T to B -> y first, then x
sorted_cell_bboxes = [
    bbox for _,_,bbox in 
    sorted(zip(y_labels, x_labels, cell_bboxes))
]

When I run this, I get the following output for sorted_cell_bboxes:
[(11, 11, 91, 92),
 (106, 11, 95, 92),
 (205, 11, 91, 91),
 (307, 11, 92, 91),
 (403, 11, 94, 91),
 (502, 10, 91, 92),
 (604, 10, 91, 92),
 (798, 10, 92, 91),
 (700, 10, 94, 92),
 (11, 107, 91, 95),
 (106, 107, 95, 95),
 (205, 107, 91, 94),
 (307, 106, 92, 95),
 (403, 106, 94, 95),
 (502, 106, 91, 95),
 (604, 106, 91, 95),
 (798, 106, 92, 95),
 (700, 106, 94, 95),
 (11, 206, 91, 91),
 (107, 206, 94, 91),
 (205, 206, 91, 91),
 (307, 206, 92, 91),
 (403, 205, 94, 92),
 (502, 205, 91, 92),
 (604, 205, 91, 92),
 (798, 205, 92, 91),
 (700, 205, 94, 92),
 ...
]


Hi, thank you very much. It works fine. BR kami

If this solves your question, be sure to click the checkmark to mark it as solved.
